# Will Phonegap or Cordova apps receive push notifications when app not opened?

Tags: android, cordova, google-cloud-messaging, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-pushplugin

I have serious doubt. If Phonegap(or Cordova) apps won't run in background how can I get the GCM/FCM push notifications when my app is not in use or not opened ?

Is there any way to solve this problem ?

What is Chrome push notifications, can I use that with Phonegap apps ?

Answer (score 4):

Using [Cordova plugin FCM](https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm), your push notifications will work when app is open or closed. Both on Android and iOS.

Your app **does not** need to be running in the background to receive push notifications.